# Finding area of paraboloid $2z = x^2 - y^2$ inside $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ using double integrals

Tags: surfaces, multiple-integral

The original problem was to find the surface area of hyperbolic paraboloid
$$2z = x^2 - y^2$$

that lies inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.

My attempt was to parametrize $(x, y, z) = (\cos u, \sin u, v)$ and get $2v = \cos2u$  from the first equation. Then I found $|[r_u, r_v]| = 1$. After this I made assumption (don't know whether it was correct or not) that area of the whole figure is $4$ times area of the part of paraboloid that lies in $y > 0, z > 0$. Now we can calculate
$$\mu S = 4\iint_S dudv = 4\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}du\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\cos2u} dv = 2$$

However I've found similar problem in my textbook (but the problem there was to find area for $z > 0$) and the answer for that was $\frac{\pi}{3}(2\sqrt2 - 1)$ which is far from what I've got.

My question is: how to get the correct answer with the parametrization that I made? I've read that the correct parametrization should be simple polar coordinates after setting $|[r_u, r_v]| = \sqrt{1 + z_x^2 + z_y^2}$, but is there a method to compute the area with the parametrization that was made above?

Comment: What makes you think that the area element -- the thing to be integrated -- would be $du ~ dv$?

Comment: My textbook says that the area of the surface $S = \{\vec{r}(u, v), (u, v) \in \overline{G}\}$ is $\mu S = \iint_G |[r_u, r_v]| dudv$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the surface area of $z>0$, it can be integrated via

$$A=\int_{x^2+y^2\le1} \sqrt{1+z_x^2 + z_y^2} \>dxdy 
= 4\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+r^2}rdr d\theta= \frac\pi3(2\sqrt2-1)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the question above is to find the answer using the parametrization above (or, at least, to find out what that parametrization gives in the case of the problem in the question).

Comment: @IPPK - note that it is integrated in cylindrical coordinates, which parametrizes as $z=z$, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$

Comment: Yes, I've made $r = 1$ so we have $z = z, x = \cos\theta, y = \sin\theta$. Oh, setting $r = 1$ should be an error... But what did I calculate then? Was it something like the area of a cylinder inside a hyperbolic paraboloid or something like that?

Comment: @IPPK - you calculate the surface area of the given parabolic inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Oh, okay. Then the last question is: will the answer for the case $z \in \mathbb{R}$ (as in the original problem) be twice the answer for the case $z > 0$?

Comment: @IPPK - correct, due to symmetry of x and y

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! It helped a lot.

Comment: @IPPK - my pleasure